# How to alter this loop to insert the word "CHANGE"

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

Here is the code I am working with:

```
words_input = "Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck Bear Bear Bear Bear Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck"

replacements = [{'Bear': ["Black", "Woods"], 'Duck': ["Bird", "Feathers"]},
                {'Bear': ["Grizzly", "Woods"], 'Duck': ["Quack", "Feathers"]},
                {'Bear': ["Grizzly", "Black"], 'Duck': ["Quack", "Bird"]}]

output = []
index_replace = 0
count_replace = {key: 0 for key in replacements[0].keys()}
for word in words_input.split():
    if count_replace[word] == len(replacements[index_replace][word]):
        # We need to cycle through the replacements
        index_replace = (index_replace + 1) % len(replacements)
        count_replace = {key: 0 for key in replacements[0].keys()}
    idx_word = count_replace[word]
    output.append(replacements[index_replace][word][idx_word])
    count_replace[word] += 1

output_words = ' '.join(output)
print(output_words)
# Bird Black Woods Feathers Quack Grizzly Woods Grizzly Black Quack Black Woods Bird Feathers
```

I would like the desired output to insert the word "`CHANGE`" everytime the dictionary list changes so that the output would look like

```
Bird Black Woods Feathers CHANGE Quack Grizzly Woods CHANGE Grizzly Black Quack CHANGE Black Woods Bird Feathers
```

instead of

```
Bird Black Woods Feathers Quack Grizzly Woods Grizzly Black Quack Black Woods Bird Feathers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `output.append("CHANGE")` when... the list changes?

```
words_input = "Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck Bear Bear Bear Bear Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck"

replacements = [{'Bear': ["Black", "Woods"], 'Duck': ["Bird", "Feathers"]},
                {'Bear': ["Grizzly", "Woods"], 'Duck': ["Quack", "Feathers"]},
                {'Bear': ["Grizzly", "Black"], 'Duck': ["Quack", "Bird"]}]

output = []
index_replace = 0
count_replace = {key: 0 for key in replacements[0].keys()}
for word in words_input.split():
    if count_replace[word] == len(replacements[index_replace][word]):
        output.append("CHANGE") # << here is the change
        # We need to cycle through the replacements
        index_replace = (index_replace + 1) % len(replacements)
        count_replace = {key: 0 for key in replacements[0].keys()}
    idx_word = count_replace[word]
    output.append(replacements[index_replace][word][idx_word])
    count_replace[word] += 1

output_words = ' '.join(output)
print(output_words)
#Bird Black Woods Feathers CHANGE Quack Grizzly Woods CHANGE Grizzly Black Quack CHANGE Black Woods Bird Feathers
```

Answer (score 0):

````
replacements = [{'Bear': ["Black", "Woods"], 'Duck': ["Bird", "Feathers"]},
                {'Bear': ["Grizzly", "Woods"], 'Duck': ["Quack", "Feathers"]},
                {'Bear': ["Grizzly", "Black"], 'Duck': ["Quack", "Bird"]}]

output = []
index_replace = 0
count_replace = {key: 0 for key in replacements[0].keys()}
for word in words_input.split():
    if count_replace[word] == len(replacements[index_replace][word]):
        # We need to cycle through the replacements
        index_replace = (index_replace + 1) % len(replacements)
        --- add--- output.append("CHANGE")
        count_replace = {key: 0 for key in replacements[0].keys()}
    idx_word = count_replace[word]
    output.append(replacements[index_replace][word][idx_word])
    count_replace[word] += 1

output_words = ' '.join(output)
print(output_words)
# Bird Black Woods Feathers Quack Grizzly Woods Grizzly Black Quack Black Woods Bird Feathers```
````